# How do you call a custom setting to open in a new window?

Tags: visualforce, class, customsetting

I have a visualforce page with custom buttons. Twas asked to add to the Custom Setting a field called ATLAS_ENDPOINT. I need to use this value to popup a new window with the link inside.

VISUALFORCE

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" sidebar="false" extensions="LEORDERSAPIExtension">
    <apex:form >
  <script>
    function finalRedirect()
    {
        window.location = "https://c.cs11.visual.force.com/apex/OrderSubmitted?&id={!Case.Id}";
    }
  </script>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Please Confirm Order Details">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Order Details" columns="2">

<apex:OutputText Label="Account ID" value="{!Case.Account.Id}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Account Number" value="{!Case.Account_Number_c__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Alternate phone"  value="{!Case.Alternate_Phone__c}" />
<apex:OutputText Label="primary street" value="{!Case.Account.BillingStreet}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary city" value="{!Case.Account.billingcity}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary state" value="{!Case.Account.BillingState}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary zip" value="{!Case.Account.BillingPostalCode}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="created by" value="{!Case.Createdby.Name}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="created by user Id" value="{!Case.Createdby}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="digital contract length (months)" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Digital_Contract_Length_Text__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary country" value="{!Case.Account.BillingCountry}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="email" value="{!Case.Contact.Email}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="fax" value="{!Case.Account.Fax}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Contact First Name" value="{!Case.Contact.FirstName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Contact Last Name" value="{!Case.Contact.LastName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Oppty Owner Manager Email" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Owner.Manager.Email}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Case Market" value="{!Case.Case_Market__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Account Name" value="{!Case.Account.Name}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Opportunity Owner First Name" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Owner.FirstName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Opportunity Owner Last Name" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Owner.LastName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Contact Phone" value="{!Case.Contact.Phone}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Account Phone" value="{!Case.Account.Phone}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Total digital monthly fees" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Total_Digital_monthly_Fees__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="total setup fees" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Total_Setup_Fees__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="website" value="{!Case.Account.Website}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!sendOrder}" value="Send Order" oncomplete="finalRedirect();"  />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

APEX CLASS

```
public class LEORDERSAPIExtension {   
     private Id caseRecordId;    public LEORDERSAPIExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {        caseRecordId = controller.getRecord().Id; 

   }        public void sendOrder() {            
              BPMIntegrationService.postCaseRecordToBPM(caseRecordId);            
 }            
  }
```

CUSTOM SETTING

```
Label BPM Integration Object Name BPM_Integration 
API Name BPM_Integration__c Setting Type Hierarchy 
Visibility Public Description  
Namespace Prefix  Created Date 8/8/2014 10:06 AM 
Last Modified Date 8/8/2014 10:08 AM Record Size 1,870
```

Comment: see Keith C's answer; note to others who might be reading this: if the custom setting is a list Custom Setting, then the controller will need to make it available with a public getter property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the value of a hierarchy custom setting field directly in Visualforce via the [$Setup global:](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_setup.htm)

```
{!$Setup.BPM_Integration__c.ATLAS_ENDPOINT__c}
```

The text that is in the setting will be merged into your page so you can reference it e.g. in some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Using Keith C's information I added the following:  window.open('{!$Setup.BPM_Integration__c.ATLAS_ENDPOINT__c}') 
I put that under the window.location line.  The final visualforce page included:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" sidebar="false" extensions="LEORDERSAPIExtension">
    <apex:form >
  <script>
    function finalRedirect()
    {
        window.location = "https://c.cs11.visual.force.com/apex/OrderSubmitted?&id={!Case.Id}";
        window.open('{!$Setup.BPM_Integration__c.ATLAS_ENDPOINT__c}')

    }
  </script>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Please Confirm Order Details">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Order Details" columns="2">

<apex:OutputText Label="Account ID" value="{!Case.Account.Id}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Account Number" value="{!Case.Account_Number_c__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Alternate phone"  value="{!Case.Alternate_Phone__c}" />
<apex:OutputText Label="primary street" value="{!Case.Account.BillingStreet}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary city" value="{!Case.Account.billingcity}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary state" value="{!Case.Account.BillingState}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary zip" value="{!Case.Account.BillingPostalCode}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="created by" value="{!Case.Createdby.Name}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="created by user Id" value="{!Case.Createdby}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="digital contract length (months)" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Digital_Contract_Length_Text__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="primary country" value="{!Case.Account.BillingCountry}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="email" value="{!Case.Contact.Email}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="fax" value="{!Case.Account.Fax}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Contact First Name" value="{!Case.Contact.FirstName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Contact Last Name" value="{!Case.Contact.LastName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Oppty Owner Manager Email" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Owner.Manager.Email}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Case Market" value="{!Case.Case_Market__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Account Name" value="{!Case.Account.Name}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Opportunity Owner First Name" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Owner.FirstName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Opportunity Owner Last Name" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Owner.LastName}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Contact Phone" value="{!Case.Contact.Phone}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Account Phone" value="{!Case.Account.Phone}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="Total digital monthly fees" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Total_Digital_monthly_Fees__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="total setup fees" value="{!Case.Opportunity__r.Total_Setup_Fees__c}"/>
<apex:OutputText Label="website" value="{!Case.Account.Website}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!sendOrder}" value="Send Order" oncomplete="finalRedirect();"  />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```